# Measuring vs gauging

Tags: measurements

How would one describe the difference between measuring and gauging? As I understand it at my company, we use a fixed tool to `gauge` something, but we will use a set of calipers to `measure` something. Is this a correct understanding?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you have it correct.

We used "go / no go" gauges to check some things and made measurements for others.

Comment: An acceptable answer on my test according to my professor was `measuring is association of a value to an object. Gauging is checking an object to a standard`